# cq5 dialog is not changing its width after increasing the size

Tags: aem

I have a dialog in cq5 which is using xtype tabpanel, I am planning to change the default dimensions of dialog using [these instructions](http://blogs.adobe.com/contentmanagement/2011/11/17/how-to-make-the-component-dialog-floating-and-set-a-default-size/) I still see the default size of dialog even though I increased the width of the xtype panel.

I got it working after I change xtype to dialog

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue, and has been present since at least CQ 5.3.  The only workaround I'm aware of is just as you said, to change the xtype to dialog, set height and width properties on the dialog node, and then add a tabpanel node as a child node of your dialog.